# read names of files from a text file and copy them to a new directory with python

Tags: python, directory

I have a comprehensive list of files and I want only to select those that contain specific data in them. For that reason I have a list(a text file) that contains name of the files that I intend to select. I want to select those files that their names are on the list and move them to a new folder. Anyone has any idea how to do that?

Comment: Sounds more suitable to use shell or command line tools on your OS... Could you not re-work it to move the files at the time you've identified they contain the "specific data"?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [shutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) library. It performs file operations, and takes inputs (filenames) as strings, thus it is right suitable for you.